# Web scraping debug print LocationURL returns unexpected value

Tags: vba, web-scraping

This code is supposed to print webpage URL into the immediate window.

```vb
Sub BrowseToSite()
    Dim IEObject As InternetExplorer
        
    'Creating new instance of the internet explorer application
    Set IEObject = New InternetExplorer
     
    'make IE app visible
    IEObject.Visible = True
        
    'navigate to URL
    IEObject.Navigate URL:="https://www.youtube.com"
        
    Do While IEObject.Busy = True Or IEObject.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")            
    Loop
        
    'Print the URL that we are currently at
    Debug.Print IEObject.LocationURL
End Sub
```

I expect `https://www.youtube.com` but I get **res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm**.

I have references set to Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft internet controls.

Comment: When I try your code I just get *[This website doesn't work in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/this-website-doesn-t-work-in-internet-explorer-8f5fc675-cd47-414c-9535-12821ddfc554) The Internet Explorer 11 will be retired and go out of support on June 15, 2022* • While it perfectly works with `Url:="https://www.google.com"`. So you might want to switch to something more modern than Internet Explorer. For example Chrome Selenium (give this a research, you can use it in a similar way and it works with Chrome).

Comment: Youtube doesn't work on IE (for me, it automatically opens Edge). Ah, Pᴇʜ beat me.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. So additionally is it better to use CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") and querySelectorAll for web scraping in the future, since IE will retire?

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ i will give it a shot.

Comment: @Ahti `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` will only return the http content but it will not (like IE) execute any JavaScript. So if the website loads only a basic structure and the actual data is loaded by JavaScript techniques like AJAX you won't be able to get the data but only the basic structure. • Easy description: Through `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` you will see the page like when you turn JavaScript off in your browser. • So depending on what you try Chrome Selenium might be the better way to go.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed description. At this moment i'm just trying to figure out how all of this works, but my future goal is to scrape information from websites: product name, price, seller and compare the stock size from time to time to see if there are any new products on sale.

Comment: In that case you should just try with the actual website, all websites behave and work differently.